# Dealing with "at least" in Permutation

Tags: permutations

For the following question (which I pulled of the internet)

> > A five member committee is to be selected from among four Math teachers and five English teachers. In how many different ways can the committee be formed under the following circumstance?
> >
> > A)   Anyone is eligible to serve on the committee.
> >
> > B)   The committee must consist of $3$ Math teachers and $2$ English teachers.
> >
> > C)   The committee must contain at least three Math teachers.
> >
> > D)   The committee must contain at least three English teachers.
> >
> > (Answer     $126$,   $40$,   $45$,   $81$)

How would I go about solving when the requirement is **at least $3$ Math Teacher** Any suggestions ? . I know that when it was $3$ Math and $2$ English teachers I simply took r=3 for math and r=2 for English in the Combination Formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you know how to do it for exactly $3$ math teachers, you also know how to do it for exactly $4$ math teachers. There are only $4$ math teachers, so those are the only two possibilities; you just have to add them up.

Comment: I still dont get it when there are $3$ Math teachers the combination is 4 and when there are 4 math teachers the combination is 5 so when there are 2 and 1 English teacher(s) the combinations are 10 and 5 respectively

Comment: Misty, there are 5 people total on the committee, so when there are 3 Math there are also 2 English and you have to account for the number of ways of choosing them, too.

Comment: Okay so for 3 Math and 2 English it will be $4 \times 10$ and when there are 4 Math and 1 English it will be  $5 \times 5$. How do I figure out for **at least** 3 Math. I am still a bit confused

Comment: @MistyD: I don't know how you got $5\cdot5$; there are only $4$ math teachers in all, so there's only one way to choose $4$ of them, not $5$ ways. On your second question: What other possibilities except for $3$ and $4$ math teachers do you see for the combination to include at least $3$ math teachers if there are $4$ math teachers in all?

Comment: @joriki sorry that was a misprint when there are 4 Math and 1 English Teacher then its $1 \times 5$

Comment: What other possibilities except for 3 and 4 math teachers do you see for the combination to include at least 3 math teachers if there are 4 math teachers in all ?  Cant think of one - 3 is the minimum and 4 is the maximum..

Comment: @MistyD: Well, there you go. If those are the only two possibilities, all you need to do is add them up.

Comment: Thanks now I get it so its (Combinations of 4 math . Combinations of 1 English) + (Combinations of 3 math . Combinations of 2 English)